# lowdb remove key value pair from db file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron, lodash, lowdb

I am using lowdb as my database. So the database file db.json looks like below.

```
{
  "posts": {
    "user1" : {
       id: 1,
       published: false
     },
     "user2" : {
       id: 2, 
       published: true
     }
  },
  "comments": {
    "article1" : {
       id: 1,
       postId: 1
     },
    "article2" : {
       id: 2,
       postId: 2
     }
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that on match of certain condition, remove the posts key with values. So my db file should look like below.

```
{
  "comments": {
    "article1" : {
       id: 1,
       postId: 1
     },
    "article2" : {
       id: 2,
       postId: 2
     }
  }
}
```

Any guide will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unset method to remove the post key from lowdb database

```
db.unset(`posts`).write()
```